# Add HTML dynamic table values Into Single INSERT statement

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, arrays

This is my Main Page which is adding dynamic rows inside table(jQuery is performing this),since i have 'n' number of rows to add,how can i perform SQL insert statement for all dynamic number of rows(with 4 different textfields).

In Simple,i have- (1,2,3,x,y,z)elements as Insert statement values,where x,y,z can be any number of rows(but every time x,y,z will be equal number of elements),along with 1,2,3 i need to add this array of x,y,z. FOR loop inside insert statement is what i get from google n stackOverflow but how do u FOR loop 4 different textfields along with 1,2,3(pre-defined elements)

More Simpler-

```
(value1,value2,value3,x,y,z);
(value1,value2,value3,a,b,c);
(value1,value2,value3,e,f,g);
(value1,value2,value3,q,w,e);
(value1,value2,value3,a,s,d);
```

How do u insert this above inside MySQL single INSERT statement?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.json-2.4.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var id = 0;

            // Add button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.add").click(function() {
                id++;
                var master = $(this).parents("table.dynatable");

                // Get a new row based on the prototype row

                var prot1= master.find(".prototype").clone();
                prot1.attr("class", "")
                prot1.find(".id").attr("value", id);

                master.find("tbody").append(prot1);
                alert(id);
            });

            // Remove button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.remove").live("click", function() {
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();

            });

            //Submit button clicked
            $('#button').click(function() {    
                //$("table tr").has("th").remove();
            var data = {
                value : []
            }
            $("table tbody tr").each(function() {

            data.value.push($('.id', this).val());
            data.value.push($('.WID', this).val());
            data.value.push($('.ac', this).val());
            data.value.push($('.tm', this).val());
            data.value.push($('.cutt', this).val());

        });

            console.log(data);
            var id = data.value.join(','); alert(id);

            var myarr1={final:data};

            var myarr2=JSON.stringify(myarr1);
            var myarr3="receivearray.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent(myarr2);

            $('#myFrame1').attr("src", myarr3);
        }); 

        });


        </script>
        <style>
            .dynatable {
                border: solid 1px #000; 
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            .dynatable th,
            .dynatable td {
                border: solid 1px #000; 
                padding: 2px 10px;
                width: 170px;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .dynatable .prototype {

            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>


            <table id="MyTable" class="dynatable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>WID</th>
                    <th>InchargeName</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th><button class="add">Add</button></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="prototype" id="pro">
                    <td><input type="text"  name="id[]" value=""  class="id" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text"  name="name[]" value="" class="WID"/></td>
                    <td><input type="text"  name="col4[]" value=""   class="ac" /></td>
                    <td><input type="text"  name="col3[]" value=""  class="tm"/></td>


                    <td><button class="remove">Remove</button>
                </tr>
        </table>


        <input type="button" id="button" value="submit"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The second part about "where x,y,z can be any number of rows(but every time x,y,z will be equal number of elements)" is totally unclear to me. Please try to clearify what do you exactly need, but have in mind, that we are no you, and obvious (for you) aspects of your task are unknown to PPL that will read this.

Comment: i have a table with add new row button.this row has 4 textfields,so each time u click ADD,a row with 4 fields will be added to my page,when i hit submit,all the rows along with outside table elements should be added.

Comment: ex. id,name,field 1,field 2,field 3. each time u hit ADD button, field 1,field 2,field 2 will add as a AJAX row, say,on submit u are adding now (1,2,x1,y1,z1)(1,2,x2,y3,z3)........(1,2,xn,yn,zn)

Comment: Too much code to read

Comment: i got the answer @Rolf, putting for loop to the insert statement precisely,thats all!!!

Answer (score 0):

This send all data in one (**ajax**) http request:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.json-2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var id = 0;

            // Add button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.add").click(function() {
                id++;
                var master = $(this).parents("table.dynatable");

                // Get a new row based on the prototype row

                var prot1= master.find(".prototype").clone();
                prot1.attr("class", "")
                prot1.find(".id").attr("value", id);

                master.find("tbody").append(prot1);
                alert(id);
            });

            // Remove button functionality
            $("table.dynatable button.remove").live("click", function() {
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();

            });

            //Submit button clicked
            $('#button').click(function() {
                //$("table tr").has("th").remove();
                var data = {
                    final:{
                        value : []
                    }
                }
                $("table tbody tr").each(function() {
                    // create an array of objects
                    data.final.value.push({
                        id: $('.id', this).val(),
                        wid: $('.WID', this).val(),
                        ac: $('.ac', this).val(),
                        tm: $('.tm', this).val(),
                        cutt: $('.cutt', this).val()
                    });
                });

                console.log(eval(data));

                $.ajax({
                    async: false,
                    url: 'receivearray.php',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    type: 'get'
                });

                $('#myFrame1').attr("src", myarr3);
            });

        });


    </script>
    <style>
        .dynatable {
            border: solid 1px #000;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        .dynatable th,
        .dynatable td {
            border: solid 1px #000;
            padding: 2px 10px;
            width: 170px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .dynatable .prototype {

        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>


<table id="MyTable" class="dynatable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>WID</th>
        <th>InchargeName</th>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th><button class="add">Add</button></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="prototype" id="pro">
        <td><input type="text"  name="id[]" value=""  class="id" /></td>
        <td><input type="text"  name="name[]" value="" class="WID"/></td>
        <td><input type="text"  name="col4[]" value=""   class="ac" /></td>
        <td><input type="text"  name="col3[]" value=""  class="tm"/></td>


        <td><button class="remove">Remove</button>
    </tr>
</table>


<input type="button" id="button" value="submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Here **receivearray.php**

```
<?php
file_put_contents('/tmp/temp.txt',var_export($_REQUEST['final'],true));
```

Comment: Hi Ivan, no AJAX going to receivearray page.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand, you won't use ajax to send data OR there's some error and ajax don't work?

Comment: got the answer outside,anywy thnx ivan